# Calculation of val_loss in Keras' multiple output

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, loss-function, multipleoutputs

I have a question about how to calculate val_loss in Keras' multiple output.
Here is an excerpt of my code.

```
nBatchSize  = 200
nTimeSteps  = 1
nInDims     = 17
nHiddenDims = 10
nFinalDims  = 10
nOutNum     = 24
nTraLen     = 300
nMaxEP      = 20
nValLen     = 50
sHisCSV     = "history.csv"

oModel = Sequential()
oModel.add(Input(batch_input_shape=(nBatchSize, nTimeSteps, nInDims)))
oModel.add(LSTM(nHiddenDims, return_sequences=True,  stateful=True))
oModel.add(LSTM(nHiddenDims, return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
oModel.add(Dense(nFinalDims, activation="relu")
oModel.add(Dense(nOutNum,    activation="linear")
oModel.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Nadam())

oModel.reset_states()
oHis = oModel.fit_generator(oDataGen, steps_per_epoch=nTraLen,
epochs=nMaxEP, shuffle=False,
validation_data=oDataGen, validation_steps=nValLen,
callbacks=[CSVLogger(sHisCSV, append=True)])

# number of cols is nOutNum(=24), number of rows is len(oEvaGen)
oPredDF = pd.DataFrame(oPredModel.predict_generator(oEvaGen, steps=len(oEvaGen))

# GTDF is a dataframe of Ground Truth
nRMSE   = np.sqrt(np.nanmean(np.array(np.power(oPredDF - oGTDF, 2))))
```

In history.csv, val_loss is written and it is written as 3317.36.
The RMSE calculated from the prediction result is 66.4.

By my understanding my Keras specification, val_loss written in history.csv
is the mean MSE of 24 outputs.
Assuming that it is correct, RMSE can be computed as 11.76 (= sqrt(3317.36/24)) from history.csv,
which is quite different from value of nRMSE (=66.4)
Just as sqrt(3317.36) = 57.6 is rather close to it.

Is my understanding of Keras specification on val_loss incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first assumption is correct, but the further derivation went wrong a bit.
As the **[MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error)** is the mean of the model's output's squared errors, as you can see in the Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/losses/):

> **mean_squared_error**
>   keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)

and in the Keras source code:

```
K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

thus the **[RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation)** is the square root of this value:

```
K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))
```

What you wrote would be the root square of the square error i.e. **RSE**.

So from your actual example:
**RSE** can be computed as `sqrt(3317.36/24) = 11.76`
**RMSE** can be computed as `sqrt(3317.36) = 57.6`

Thus the RMSE (and nRMSE) values provided by the model are correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind advice. It's all clear now.

In my model, the output is not a scalar but a 24-dimensional vector, so I thought it would be handled as 24 multiple outputs in Keras. And I thought rmse1, rmse2..rmse23 would be calculated for each output y1, y2 ... y23, and val_loss be the sum of them (= rmse1 + rmse2 .. rmse23).

But thanks to your advice, I was able to notice that it was treated as a single output.

Comment: @shamada You're welcome! If you found my answer correct, please accept my answer if useful please upvote it.